# How to add custom static file directives in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want create custom static folders in Rails 4.

For example, I want to put my `.js` files in the `assets/js` dir and not in `assets/javascripts`. The css should be in `assets/css` and not in `assets/stylesheets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `application.rb` file:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/js"
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/css"
```

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) is a good guide on the Asset Pipeline

Answer (score 0):

According to the following code snippet in `railtie.rb`

```
module Sprockets
  class Railtie < ::Rails::Railtie
    LOOSE_APP_ASSETS = lambda do |filename, path|
      path =~ /app\/assets/ && !%w(.js .css).include?(File.extname(filename))
    end

    class OrderedOptions < ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions
      def configure(&block)
        self._blocks << block
  end
end
```

all the `.js` and `.css` files inside `app/assets` are auto_loaded in the precompile array. So you can simply use your assets inside the `app/assets/js` and `app/assets/css` without writing an extra line of code in `application.rb`.

Just add the following code in `assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require_tree ../js/.
```

and similar changes in `application.css` as well

> Note: if you want to load controller/page specific js/css then never include then in `application.js/css` files.. just use them as described here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets